# Trying to record screen with webcam separately

Tags: screen-recorder, obs-studio

I am trying to record my screen and my webcam separately in HD. So basically I have 2 1920x1080 screens that I am trying to record.

What I did was I created a canvas of 3840x1080 and placed them side by side as shown in this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8w9x31FBUo&t=193s).

When I try to zoom in on one screen I get blurry texts. I have uploaded my entire process in this video [here](https://youtu.be/GvWNk8cDgto).

Also, my OBS log is this https://obsproject.com/logs/i15LckmC1hJI9syR

I would love any info on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't OBS have an output size that is different to the canvas size? Like a render resolution setting in the video output... I've used it in the past but don't have access right now.

Comment: @Mokubai no it does not. I have uploaded my entire problem on youtube in the video